# Return the same ViewData twice from controller to View result in NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Hello guys I am still really new to Asp.net and C#. I am writing a management system overseeing office activities. I ran into a problem where I am passing a ViewModel Object that contains a list, Case and int to the view from the controller. If the newly created case has the same ID, it would return the same ViewModel Object back to the POST controller, but when the object got passed from view to the post controller,every list Object is null except for primitive types and the Case. I dont understand why the same object is passed around but when it passes to the controller from the view all the list that was just used to populate the html are null, is this because of injection or just how model binding works? THanks a lot

The View just has a for loop displaying every item in the TopTenList. it has the @model binding statement on the top.
Heres the View

```
@model LabManager.InputModels.CaseInputModel
@inject LabManager.Data.ApplicationDbContext _dbContext
@using LabManager.ModelExtensions

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Overview";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Stylesheet{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Case/index.css" />
}

<div id="home-view">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#topTen">
                Top Ten Priority Cases
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="topTen" class="collapse show" data-parent="#home-view">
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>bunch of names</tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{int i = 1;}
                        @foreach (var item in Model.TopTenList)
                        {
                            show somethings.
                        }
```

Heres the controller.

```
public ActionResult Create(int setPriority)
{
    CaseInputModel input = new CaseInputModel {
        SelectedPriority = setPriority,
    };
    input.SetTopTenList(_dbContext);
    return View(input);
}

// POST: Takes info from the input model and creates a new case in the db
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(CaseInputModel inputs)
{
    //if case id already exist in the database, return view()
    if (DbContext.Cases.Any(m => m.CaseId == inputs.NewCase.CaseId))
    {
        inputs.ErrorMessage = "Error: Case ID already exists";
        return View(inputs);
    }
```

Hers the Model:

```
   public class Case
    {
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("[^0-9]")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CaseId { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

Heres the CaseInputModel(ViewModel Object)

```
public class CaseInputModel
    {
        public CaseInputModel()
        {
            NewCase = new Case();
            RegularCaseList = new List<Case>();
        }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public int SelectedPriority { get; set; }
        public Case NewCase { get; set; }
        public List<Case> RegularCaseList { get; set; }
        public List<Case> TopTenList { get; set; }

        public void SetTopTenList(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            TopTenList = PriorityNodeExtensions.ToSortedList(dbContext.TopTens, 
            dbContext);
        }
```

Comment: Could you share your model and razor view?And the reason for why your view populate the null object is because the object is null when you post to the controller.And when you return view with model,it would render null data in html.

Comment: I will add that. You are right that when its posted to the controller. The get request to controller return a view(input), which has a list of top10 cases. But when its passed back from the view to post controller,  only 2 attributes of the objects(Case, int) are saved, the rest are null.

Comment: What you provided is not helpful to reproduce your issue.You need to provide the rest razor view about how do you model binding.And you could only receive the Case and int,please tell us the specific property name of the two objects in the InputModel.Your code have some errors:1.In you get method,you return input model,but your razor view need a IEnumerable<Case>,did you miss other razor view?2.In your get method,you only set two property value,be sure your razor view have other properties' html and fill the data,otherwise,you could not pass the whole data to the controller.

Comment: @Rena, Hello there I am sorry for not replying sooner. I actually still do have a problem. I will update my question, trying to get more pictures in. Thanks so much for the follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firsly,you need know that for each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the prefix.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#complex-types

Here is a simple demo about how to pass the data to the controller:

View:

```
@model InputModel

<form asp-action="Create">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>bunch of names</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>SelectedPriority</td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.SelectedPriority" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>New Case</td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.NewCase.Id" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.NewCase.CaseId" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.NewCase.Notes" /></td>
            </tr>
            @{int i = 0;}
            @foreach (var item in Model.TopTenList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>TopTenList_@i</td>
                    <td><input name="TopTenList[@i].Id" asp-for="@item.Id" /></td>
                    <td><input name="TopTenList[@i].CaseId" asp-for="@item.CaseId" /></td>
                    <td><input name="TopTenList[@i].Notes" asp-for="@item.Notes" /></td>
                </tr>
                i++;
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="create" />
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:**

return view with model it could render the model successfully,but you could not render the TopTenList.Be sure you have create the input for the model properties and debug the action to check if you have passed the TopTenList to the post method.If you only render the data by using `@Model.Property` it would not pass to the backend.

View:

```
 @model CaseInputModel
<form asp-action="Create">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>bunch of names</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.ErrorMessage != null)
            {
                @Model.ErrorMessage
            }
            <tr>
                <td>SelectedPriority</td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.SelectedPriority" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>New Case</td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.NewCase.Id" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.NewCase.CaseId" /></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.NewCase.Notes" /></td>
            </tr>
            @{int i = 0;}
            @foreach (var item in Model.TopTenList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.Id
                        <input name="TopTenList[@i].Id" asp-for="@item.Id" hidden />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.CaseId
                        <input name="TopTenList[@i].CaseId" asp-for="@item.CaseId" hidden />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Notes
                        <input name="TopTenList[@i].Notes" asp-for="@item.Notes" hidden />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                i++;
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="create" />
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I might not have explained the problem well. Please bear with me. The create  page works fine reguarly, populate the toptenlist in the Create Controller Method and pass it to the view. However if I input the same case ID# thats already in the database, i have it return the same view of the same ViewModel with an errormessage, this causes a problem since this would "refresh" the page and the TopTenList is lost. When the Get Method Create is called it creates the TopTen and pass to the view. The view populate everything and passes the same ViewModel Object back to the HTTP Method Create.

Comment: Now, when the http method creates get that viewModel, "input" in this case. it only has the int variable priority, the case object, and toptenlist is null. thus when this input is then returned to the view , the toptenlist cannot populate because its null.

Comment: Hi @HeChuan,Sorry for late reply.Please check my updated answer.